# Google Cloud instance suddenly cannot access internet

Tags: google-compute-engine

On a Google compute engine instance running Centos 7 that has been running without problems for five years, I wanted to update the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate as I do every two months, and ran certbot renew and it failed when it couldn't reach: acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org.

> sudo certbot renew
> Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
> Failed to renew certificate [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) with error: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

Same kind of error running yum update:

> sudo yum update
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
> Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"

I have no problem connecting to the server but apparently the server has lost the ability to make outbound connections to the internet.   I have no idea why, or how to fix it.  How do I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: The system log files will probably explain why. If you have not patched and rebooted the server in five years, check that you have sufficient free space for the services to operate properly.

Comment: There are lots of log files, which one?   The server is up-to-date with the latest kernel and all software updates. By confidence the free memory and free disk space are both 47%.  So no running out of space is occurring. Plus it has a swap disk so virtual memory is also available.

Comment: Start with `/var/log/messages`. Then Google search for articles that explain Centos log files.